# Reading Text from Pdf in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf

> How to read the content of a uploaded pdf file in asp.net ?

I tried but i am unable getting the content of a Uploaded File.

I stuck with this Problem. If you have any Source code, Please provide me or Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/) library. You would specifically be interested in [PdfTextExtractor](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/PdfTextExtractor.html) class which has a getTextFromPage() method.

```
PdfTextExtractor pdfParser =new PdfTextExtractor(new PdfReader("pdf_file_location"));
pdfParser .getTextFromPage(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) (disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle) to extract text from PDF files.

Please take a look at a sample that shows [how to extract text from PDF](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/pdf-text/extract).